# What do I need in order for my Microsoft VS C++ code to be compiled and run?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I  notice when starting with template code, in this case by picking the option "Windows Desktop Application," MS VS shows me the option to build a solution, i.e the option to run the program. This option is not present if I create a blank .CPP file and try and compile and run code from scratch. What am I missing? I don't want to start with template code. Cheers.

Comment: Try to use windows desktop wizard, there you can choose empty progect

Comment: ***What am I missing?*** A project of some type.

Comment: ***I don't want to start with template code.*** It's basically a requirement, unless you want to edit in the IDE then do the building yourself in the command line (which will be a lot of work if the project is more than trivial).

Comment: You probably want to start reading here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Then here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019)

Comment: If template code is a requirement, how come there are online c++ compilers that don't come with template code? A better way to put it is "What makes code valid to be compiled and run?" Cheers.

Comment: Online compilers have different limitations and requirements than a full desktop IDE application.

Comment: if your code is just a single file you can spend an hour and read about how to do it the manual way using the last 2 links I posted. If your code is dozens of files (or up to thousands of files like mine is) this becomes ridiculous. Although with that said I use CMake to generate my project instead of the template but the end result is similar.

Comment: If all you want is to put many `c++` source files in some folder and build each file as it's own independent console application you may want to consider using Visual Studio Code. The documentation:  [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) with the shown `tasks.json` default to build the selected file as its own console application.

Comment: Also it may be a good thing for you to learn the manual steps. This will give you a better understanding on what happens when you build a c++ application.